# In a dockerized ubuntu instance how do I get nano to display/work right?

Tags: ssh, windows, virtual-console

When I apt-get install nano in a docker instance of `ubuntu:trusty` nano's display is seriously messed up, what do I need to do to fix this?

I've tried vi/vim as well, and arrow keys are broken.

[image]

In the image above, for example, there are "B" characters scattered about... I'm SSHing to an Ubuntu 14.04LTS host, and connecting to the local docker on that host.  I'm guessing it's some terminal setting on the ubuntu host, or local, but it's irritating to say the least, and not sure where to start on this.

Comment: You'll most likely need to be much more specific than " seriously messed up".

Comment: @Seth added a screenshot.

Comment: Are you SSHing from Windows? If so what SSH client are you using?

Comment: Seth, "OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014" ...  Installed with msysgit/git-extensions - most of the *nix tools I use in windows come via that route...

Comment: Updated to latest msysgit, which puts it at `OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014` now.

Answer (score 0):

I've since switched terminals to the [Windows Terminal from the Windows Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701) on a more recent release of Windows 10 (Build 19042, but 20H2 should work).

I'm also now using Docker Desktop with WSL2, which I wholly recommend..

Between these two changes, I rarely see any oddities now.